# PHP require problem with "./"

Tags: php, include, require-once

I have a file index.php in root directory:

```
<?php
require_once "./include/common.php";
?>
```

and file common.php in include folder:

```
<?php
require_once "globalConfig.php";
?>
```

file globalConfig in the same folder with common.php. The tree folder as:

xxx/index.php

xxx/include/common.php

xxx/include/globalConfig.php

index.php run normally. But if I change file common.php as:

```
<?php
require_once "./globalConfig.php";
?>
```

PHP show a warning that it cannot find the globalConfig.php file. What is the difference? I think int the case with "./", the most outside including file (index.php) will find the globalConfig.php in its current directory.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395909/php-include-all-paths-get-messed-up, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429780/include-and-path-problem, and lots of other questions from a search for "php include path" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your index.php add

```
define('BASE_PATH',str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)));
```

And then within common.php include like so.

```
require_once BASE_PATH . '/includes/globalConfig.php';
```

This will find the exact path and standerize the slashes, then whenever you use `BASE_PATH` alsways include from the root of your htdocs, ie index.php.

Comment: As the str_replace converts backslashes to slashes its windows and linux compat, I use in every project. Your Welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The path is relative to the current working directory; in a web context (php-cgi), this is the directory where the initially invoked script (the one that gets started directly instead of through on `include`) resides. 
An easy workaround:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/foobar.inc.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the path (i.e. "./") is relative to the *BASE* script, not the file it's contained within. For this reason, I usually use absolute paths when including scripts.